# How can i texture wihout applying mirror?

Tags: modifiers, mirror-modifier

On my mesh i have serial number 0 to 10 and i have mirror it. Other side its starting from 0 but texture is flip.

[image]

[image]

I tried the Flip U and Flip V option but for me did not work. **Without applying mirror modifier** i want to achieve the right hand result. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: The Flip U is the right option, it looks like you have an older blender version  that may have a bug? In 2.92 this option is named Mirror U.

Comment: @Denis Can u plz share screenshot. I have download todays version same result. Can i see ur result plz.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/bdb1dd5e0deca4b3d721bd33ea301d04

Comment: @Denis@Denis as u have seen on right hand side the 0 is in cut hole. But your image 0 is not

Comment: You cant flip the image and start with zero, you would need to make a new texture where the digits are flipped individually